# Creating a virtualenv for python3.7.0 in ubuntu is not working

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

Following is display in my terminal:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to make sure your virtualenv does not work. I suggest that you should try something simpler for debugging:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

If this line of code works then your problem is that you don't have zlib installed properly.

```
No module named 'zlib'
```

Otherwise, please update the error while your environment running the print command for more co

Answer (score 0):

looks like your python at system level is not configured correctly.
try following:

1. apt remove virtualenv # remove virtualenv
2. apt-get install -y -q zlib1g-dev python-pip  # install zlib, python-pip
3. wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/Python-3.7.4.tgz
   tar xzf Python-3.7.4.tgz
   cd Python-3.7.4
   ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions  
   --enable-ipv6 --with-cxx-main=/usr/bin/gcc --with-ensurepip
   make -j $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) altinstall
4. pip3 install virtualenv==16.0.0
5. virtualenv -p "python3.7" xyz